Are M365 apps like Excel activated by logging in?
I have a Windows 10 PC with M365 apps installed - Word, Excel.
The PC is connected to the internet but I am no longer able to logon from Excel or Word to my M365 account, but only from that PC. It is by design that I cannot login, I do not seek any fix for that.
Will the license for M365 apps become invalid after 180 days on that PC?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-licensing-activation-microsoft-365-apps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-extended-offline-access



Yes, Microsoft 365 Apps is licensed on a “per user” basis.
If the computer goes offline for more than 30 days, Microsoft 365 Apps enters reduced functionality mode until the next time a connection can be made.
"Because of its online activation features, Microsoft 365 Apps won't work on computers that are completely cut off from the internet. For those computers, we recommend installing Office LTSC Professional Plus 2021 and using a traditional activation method such as Key Management Service (KMS) or Active Directory Domain Services." This is from link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-licensing-activation-microsoft-365-apps#activating-microsoft-365-apps
----- Update ------
If you do not sign account into Microsoft 365 Apps, you will not use Office successfully.
Once you open one, it will ask you sign into an account.


Thanks, I know that it is per user. The question was, what happens after 30 or 180 days of not logging in, but the apps having the internet access. Reduced mode is possible/probable but it is not written anywhere in the article exactly like that.

Office 365 (Microsoft 365) cannot be used without an active subscription. Offline entitlement isn’t equivalent to not having an active subscription
